# VS Debugger cannot connect to iPhone in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I am working on a Xamarin apps in my windows machine and I am trying to use my iPhone for debugging. VS says that I need to launch my application on the device. If I launch the app in my iPhone, the app crash. I am using vs 2022.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myobG.png)

Comment: Check  the device log, what error message shows when the crash happens?

Comment: How can I check the device log?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/enhanced-device-logging-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

Have similar problem on Visual Studio 2022 for Mac 17.5.6 (build 3), application build and deploy (im see dev icon on iPhone) but after have infinite connect to device.

Im look at my **application profile**, and that was **expired**.

Fix that by that steps:

1. Renew profile on Apple Developer account
2. Download it to VS ( VS -> Preferences -> Publishing -> Apple Developer Account -> (Choose neded Account) -> View Detail -> Download all profiles)